# jQuery JSON parse and apend data on different placement

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I have a page and I want to show and refresh different ads on different locations. I'm getting response from PHP File successfully via AJAX but unable to append them to specific placements.

HTML CODE

```
<script>var ads = [];</script>
<div id="ad-728x90">fhhfgh</div>

<!-- Page Content -->
<div class="container">

    <!-- Heading Row -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <img class="img-responsive img-rounded" src="http://placehold.it/900x350" alt="">
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-8 -->
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h1>Business Name or Tagline</h1>
            <p>This is a template that is great for small businesses. It doesn't have too much fancy flare to it, but it makes a great use of the standard Bootstrap core components. Feel free to use this template for any project you want!</p>
            <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#">Call to Action!</a>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->

    <hr>

    <!-- Call to Action Well -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="well text-center">
                This is a well that is a great spot for a business tagline or phone number for easy access!
            </div>

            <div id="ad-300x250" class="ads"></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
```

Javascript / jQuery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">ads.push("728x90", "300x250");</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
    function loadAds()
    {
        $.post('ads.php', { adID: ads }, function (e) {

            if (e.status == 'error')
            {
                $('.ads').each(function ()
                {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            }
            else if (e.status == 'ok')
            {
                var data = e.data;
                $.each(data, function (adID)
                {
                    $('#ad-' + adID).find('.ads').html();
                });
            }
        }, 'json');
    }

    loadAds();

});
</script>
```

JSON Response:

> {"status":"ok","data":{"728x90":"\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t
>
> 728x90 ads</p>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>","300x250":"\r\n\t\r\n\t\t\r\n\t\t\t
>
> 300x250 ads</p>\r\n\t\t</div>\r\n\t</div>"}}

Comment: So what exactly not working? What's the value of `adID` in `each`? Do you know that `html()` without parameters just receives data form jq-object?

Comment: $('#ad-' + adID).find('.ads').html("here your variable");

Comment: `$('#ad-' + adID).find('.ads').html();` returns existing html string...doesn't set anything.

Comment: i think bug in your $.each loop try this $.each(data, function (key,value)
                {
                    $('#ad-' + key).find('.ads').html();
                });

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following should place data in proper id

```
$.each(data, function (adID, adHtml){
      $('#ad-' + adID).html(adHtml);
});
```

The html shown in question doesn't show any children with class `ads` in `<div id="ad-728x90">` so `find('.ads')` was removed

Question needs clarification of expected results if this doesn't work

Comment: Thank you @charlietfl it works fien after removing `.find('.ads')`. Could you little bit explain what is doing `adHtml`?

Comment: think of it as `$.each(data, function (key, value)...`  .... `adHtml` is the `value`

Comment: One more thing as I mentioned my question. I want to refresh the ads after 30-60 secs also. Could you please update your answer for it.

Comment: `setInterval(loadAds,60*1000);`

Comment: Where exactly I have to place `setInterval(loadAds,60000);`?

Comment: Just to keep it organized ...would put it right after you call it the first time